# Writting the Floer map in local coordinates using the exponential chart

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, floer-homology

Following Salamon's Notes in Floer Homology , consider the Floer equation

$$\mathcal{F}(u):=\partial_su+J_t(\partial_tu+\nabla H_t(u))=0$$

Then we can write in local coordinates

$$\mathcal \Phi_u^{-1}(\xi)\circ F(\exp_u \xi)$$

Now my question is, what is this exponential map with respect to what metric ? Can we consider any metric on $M$ that has positive injectivity radius and we will get the same result on the linearizatin of the Floer map and we can do everything the same way ? Or do we need this metric to be with the one given by the compatible almost complex structure $J$? If so where do we use this fact ?

My question for this is because sometimes we want to consider the Floer equation where the almost complex structure $J$ is time dependent, so we would obtain a family of metrics $g_t$, and hence this exponential map would have to be with respect to this family of metrics, and then so would the covariant derivatives. To avoid these "complications" I was wondering if we could just pic any metric with positive injectivity radius.

I have tried checking this myself, and I didn't find any problem with just using a random metric provided this has positive injectivity radius , the only thing is that the covariant derivatives appearing in the linearization of the Floer map are coming from this metric, however I don't think this is a problem.

In the literature I did not find any good answer to this. I have found some papers where the authors just say to a pick a metric, but in Oh's book of Symplectic topology and Floer homology he does pick the family of metrics. Therefore I am not sure if one can do the desired generalization.

Any enlightenment is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a way to show that the limit matrices $S^{\pm}(t)=\lim _{s \rightarrow \pm \infty} S(s, t)=\Phi^{-1} J\left(\nabla_{t} \Phi-\nabla_{\Phi} X_{t}(u)\right)$ at page 15 in Salamon note are symmetric? I don't this is true if you just choose a random metric. You need to use the compatibility of the metric there.